# Javascript Custom Word or String Frequency Counter

Tags: javascript, split, reduce, frequency, word-count

I've been looking at many similar questions, but none of the solutions (as far as I could find) apply to my specific use case.

**Explanation / Situation**

I have been logging my key input for the last couple of weeks. Just for fun, I am experimenting with custom keyboard layouts and so I wanted some chart or heatmap to begin with reflecting my key input frequency.

This is a sample of the keylogger data:

```
[left-cmd]sdfdsfs[esc][left-ctrl]e[left-ctrl]xytial -f /var/log/ke[tab][return][up][left][left][left][left][left][del][del]ai[return][left-cmd]  [left-cmd][left-cmd]6[del]3[left][left][right][del][del]10[left]a[left]a[esc][left-option] [left-option]gst[left-ctrl]e[left-ctrl]hgst[return]g[left-option] replacepasswordhere[left-option][left-cmd]r[left-cmd][right-shift]c[right-shift]ure[del]
```

**Progression**

I mapped out all the characters that I want to see the frequency of (basically all characters/keys). I tried some things that ended up not being really useful. Also, the answers to the word frequency counter questions are all some variation of this:

```js
function wordFreq(string) {
    var words = string.replace(/[.]/g, '').split(/\s/);
    var freqMap = {};
    words.forEach(function(w) {
        if (!freqMap[w]) {
            freqMap[w] = 0;
        }
        freqMap[w] += 1;
    });

    return freqMap;
}
```

The thing is that I don't have a clear separation between my keys, so as far as I know a simple `.split()` won't get me far.

**Current approach**

I have been trying to find some way of splitting the string of input text into a useful array. I've spent hours trying to do this that I am almost starting to hate the word reduce.

I don't expect a typed-out answer but just want to ask if there's a way to split this the way I want or maybe a completely different approach, that I could look into. (I'll do my own research, I just need some advice or opinions from other developers to get me started) I am basically blinded by tunnel vision trying to split the string how I need it.

This is what I am trying to get the array to look like, by taking a section of the sample mentioned in the beginning in mind:

```js
const keys = ['[left-cmd]', 's', 'd', 'f', 'd', 's', 'f', 's', '[esc]', '[left-ctrl]', 'e', '[left-ctrl]', 'x', 'y', 't', 'i', 'a', 'l',' ', '-', 'f', ' ', '/', 'v', 'a', 'r', '/', 'l', 'o', 'g', '/', 'k', 'e', '[tab]', '[del]', '[return]', '[up]']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading the strings having 2 possible states: normal char, or inside a bracket char. If it's normal char I place it as token. If it's inside a bracket I aggregate it until I find a closing bracket. Then I place that as a token. Until end of string.

```js
var str = "[left-cmd]sdfdsfs[esc][left-ctrl]e[left-ctrl]xytial -f /var/log/ke[tab][return][up][left][left][left][left][left][del][del]ai[return][left-cmd]  [left-cmd][left-cmd]6[del]3[left][left][right][del][del]10[left]a[left]a[esc][left-option] [left-option]gst[left-ctrl]e[left-ctrl]hgst[return]g[left-option] replacepasswordhere[left-option][left-cmd]r[left-cmd][right-shift]c[right-shift]ure[del]"

function tokenize(str) {
  var state = "normal";
  var tokens = [];
  var bucket = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str[i];
    if (state == "normal") {
      if (c == '[') {
        state = "brackets";
        bucket = []
        continue;
      }
      tokens.push(c);
    }
    if (state == "brackets") {
      if (c == ']') {
        state = "normal";
        tokens.push('[' + bucket.join("") + ']');
        continue;
      }
      bucket.push(c);
    }
  }
  return tokens;
}

console.log(tokenize(str))
```

Comment: No way, this works perfectly! I was overthinking it so hard. (could you maybe tell me or change the meaning of variable `c`?

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would be obvious that `c` stands for `char` in this context.

Comment: It is, at least, It would be if I didn't spend the whole night (or 2) on this and just had some sleep. Coffee has its limitations and I have clearly reached them.

Comment: Do you think this would be the most efficient way of doing this? 60MB of text is quite a lot haha. Anything I could look into to optimize this?

Comment: Yes I think it's very efficient. You can use this exact function with array as parameter instead of string. I don't know which is faster.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! Do you mind upvoting the question so I can finally pass the stupid badge haha

Comment: I thought I did, sorry!