# PHP: Output string in a pattern

Tags: php, data-structures

I've been trying to output the input in the fashion shown in the comment section of the code below. I'm unable to get it right however hard I try. Can you please help me correct it

```
<?php 
 header('Content-type: text/plain');

 /*
 input: 
  1,"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11

 o/p: 
  1
  3,4
  5
  6
  7,8,9
  10
  11
  */

 $str = '1,"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11';
 //print_r(explode(",", $str));
 $arr = explode(",", $str);
 $end_qte = false;
 $start_qte = false;
 foreach($arr as $elm) {
  if (stripos($elm,'"') === FALSE && $end_qte) {
   echo $elm . "\n";
   echo "hi";
   $end_qte = false;
  } else if ($start_qte) {
   echo "," . $elm;
  } else if (stripos($elm,'"') == 0) {
   echo trim($elm,"\"");
   $start_qte = true;
  } else if (stripos($elm,'"') == 1) {
   echo "," . trim($elm,"\"") . "\n";
   $end_qte = true;
   $start_qte = false;
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: I'm not good at RegEx but if anyone wants to tackle that as an answer, you can try replacing the commas that exist within quotes with another symbol. Then explode the string with the comma, and just replace the new symbol in the output with the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Use my "state machine" to parse the file (based on a similar recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73214910/3807365) of mine in javascript)

```php
$str = '1,"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11';

function tokenize($str)
{
    $state = "normal";
    $tokens = [];
    $current = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $c = $str[$i];

        if ($state == "normal") {
            if ($c == ',') {
                if ($current) {
                    $tokens[] = $current;
                    $current = "";
                }
                continue;
            }
            if ($c == '"') {
                $state = "quotes";
                $current = "";
                continue;
            }
            $current .= $c;
        }
        if ($state == "quotes") {
            if ($c == '"') {
                $state = "normal";
                $tokens[] = $current;
                $current = "";
                continue;
            }
            $current .= $c;
        }
    }
    if ($current) {
        $tokens[] = $current;
        $current = "";
    }
    return $tokens;
}

$result = tokenize($str);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3,4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7,8,9
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 11
)

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple with using a regex:

```
$str = '1,"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/(".*?")|([^,]+)/', $str, $matches);
$withoutQuotes = array_map(fn($e) => str_replace('"', '', $e), $matches[0]);
echo implode("\n", $withoutQuotes);
```

gives

```
1
3,4
5
6
7,8,9
10
11
```

Answer (score 0):

There *are* a number of ways to parse this.

But, I think it's a mistake to split up the string on commas, even if they are inside a quoted string. Doing so makes it difficult to differentiate between commas that are delimiters vs commas inside quotes (which are just ordinary characters)

I'd split things up by looking for the leftmost comma *or* quote.

I think the easiest way is with regexes.

---

Since you originally used many language tags, here's a `perl` solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# split -- split up string

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{

    $opt_d = $ENV{"DEBUG"} != 0;

    $str = '1,"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11';

    while ($str ne "") {
        dbgprt("master: LOOP str='%s'\n",$str);

        # add ordinary text
        if ($str =~ s/^([^,"]+)//) {
            $out = $1;
            dbgprt("master: NORM out='%s' str='%s'\n",$out,$str);
            push(@out,$out);
            next;
        }

        # get the delimiter: either comma or quote
        $str =~ s/^(.)//;
        $out = $1;
        dbgprt("master: DLM out='%s' str='%s'\n",$out,$str);

        # handle a quoted string
        if ($out eq '"') {
            # get all leading non-quote chars
            $str =~ s/([^"]+)//;
            $out = $1;

            push(@out,$out);

            # strip trailing quote
            $str =~ s/^"//;

            dbgprt("master: QUO out='%s' str='%s'\n",$out,$str);
        }
    }

    foreach $out (@out) {
        printf("%s\n",$out);
    }
}

sub dbgprt
{

    printf(@_)
        if ($opt_d);
}
```

---

Here is the debug output:

```
master: LOOP str='1,"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: NORM out='1' str=',"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: LOOP str=',"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: DLM out=',' str='"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: LOOP str='"3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: DLM out='"' str='3,4",5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: QUO out='3,4' str=',5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: LOOP str=',5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: DLM out=',' str='5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: LOOP str='5,6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: NORM out='5' str=',6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: LOOP str=',6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: DLM out=',' str='6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: LOOP str='6,"7,8,9",10,11'
master: NORM out='6' str=',"7,8,9",10,11'
master: LOOP str=',"7,8,9",10,11'
master: DLM out=',' str='"7,8,9",10,11'
master: LOOP str='"7,8,9",10,11'
master: DLM out='"' str='7,8,9",10,11'
master: QUO out='7,8,9' str=',10,11'
master: LOOP str=',10,11'
master: DLM out=',' str='10,11'
master: LOOP str='10,11'
master: NORM out='10' str=',11'
master: LOOP str=',11'
master: DLM out=',' str='11'
master: LOOP str='11'
master: NORM out='11' str=''
1
3,4
5
6
7,8,9
10
11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Craig, but I would prefer an PHP solution as I need to be better at it before I can think of other languages like Perl. Your time and efforts are much appreciated.

Comment: @PramodGangadar [simple] PHP and perl are similar. And, PHP has regexes. So, it may give you ideas (e.g. note the comments).